# FLTK realtime plotting

Tags: plot, graph, jquery-animate, fltk

Please help me plot real time graph with Fast Light Tool Kit(FLTK) 1.3.8.
I use eclipse CDT. Referred to some code at [this](https://www.seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/) location but could not help.
I am a beginner (for FLTK).
Require to plot a single variable something like [this](http://www.genlogic.com/html5_demos/rt_chart_demo.html)
please help. Sorry for English. This is my first question.

Comment: I answered [VLC media player installation on RHEL 9](https://superuser.com/q/1810212/) that you asked and was migrated from Stack Overflow Q&A to Super User Q&A. Please sign up on Super User Q&A to comment or ask questions about my answer.